how to write HTACCESS rule for parsing all files of a folder to php page along with query parameters?
I have a web app in which there is a folder named "customers" and inside this folder there are subfolder with random strings for each customer and it contains various data like PDFs , text files , images etc. I want to add some authentication so that only logged in users can view this data or they can create a simple url for sharing with tokens-(example.com/data/customers/customer1/bill_01.pdf?token=1234) .
How to write htaccess rule so that script present in "example.com/data/check.php?file=FILE_PATH&token=TOKEN1234" can determine if token is correct and just stream the data which was requested or deny when someone opens (example.com/data/customers/customer1/bill_01.pdf?token=1234) .

You're saying: "there are subfolder with random strings for each customer", but in the only URL example you give you use: "customer1", which isn't random at all. Are you also asking how to map the https://example.com/data/customers/customer1/bill_01.pdf URL to a random directory? While at the same time authenticating a token? What should happen when either of those two operations fail?

In general I like to do all operations in PHP, just because it is easier. So I use a .htaccess file that redirects all URL's to one index.php file using RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]. It keeps the .htaccess file simple.

@KIKOSoftware i tried this but this is for some reason not returning ?query parameters and values in "index.php"

Well, it should, see: QSA|qsappend. There are other options to try...

@KIKOSoftware it worked perfectly ! Thankyou

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /file.php?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

The "file.php" handles authentication and logging of access.
after successful authentication , it just sends the same data that was requested.
Also using this in file.php for handling different file types-
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$ext = finfo_file($finfo,$q);
header('Content-Type: '.$ext); 

